# Generated add Text function passes as null in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an input field that gets an autogenerated string from an onClick event, but when i submit my post request, it shows up as null. When i manually type in a string, it takes that value in and posts it perfectly.

Here is my component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div class="mat-form-field">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"
             [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.name.errors }" style="margin-bottom: 4px">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="City" formControlName="city"
             [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.city.errors }" style="margin-bottom: 4px">

    <div class="flex">
      <input #input class="form-control" placeholder="ReferenceNumber" formControlName="referenceNumber" disabled>
      <mat-icon (click)="addText()" style="cursor: pointer">autorenew</mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button mat-raised-button id="modal-action-button">Add Supplier</button>
    <button mat-raised-button id="modal-cancel-button" (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

and my component.ts:

```js
addText(){
  this.input.nativeElement.focus();
  const startPos = this.input.nativeElement.selectionStart;
  const value = this.input.nativeElement.value;
  this.genCode = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 6).toUpperCase() + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 6).toUpperCase();
  this.input.nativeElement.focus();
  this.input.nativeElement.value= this.genCode;
}

submitForm() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.form.invalid) { return }

  const formData: any = new FormData();
  formData.append("name", this.form.get('name').value);
  formData.append("city",this.form.get('city').value);
  formData.append("referenceNumber",this.form.get('referenceNumber').value);

  this._Supplier.AddSupplier(new Suppliers(this.form))
    .subscribe( response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)));

  if (this.submitted == true){
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
  this.onSubmitted.emit('done');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set form value like this :

```js
addText() {

  const randomText = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 6).toUpperCase() + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 6).toUpperCase();

  this.form.patchValue({
    referenceNumber: randomText
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set ur form group to constructor and add set this to ref all form builder in program.

I made at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrzymh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and edit from ur code

Can you try this.
Ref. [Angular - Forms](https://angular.io/start/forms)